# HTML Table data will disappear after page refresh

Tags: json, ajax, jsp, jax-rs

I am using a web service to get data from MySQL database and show them in a HTML Table. And it is working data will appear in the table. But when I reload the page Table data will disappear. How can I fix that? How can I keep data even page reloaded?

HTML

```
<body>
    <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
    <table id="tab">

    </table>
</body>
```

And the following JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSearch").click(function() 
    {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Service/Rest/cart/get/cart",function(data)
        {
            var tb = $("#tab");
            $.each(data,function(i,value)
            {
                tb.append("<tr><td>Product Name: " + value.name + "</td><td>Price: " + value.price + "    </td><td>Description: " + value.description + "</td></tr>");
            });
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $( document ).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Service/Rest/cart/get/cart",function(data)
        {
            var tb = $("#tab");
            $.each(data,function(i,value)
            {
                tb.append("<tr><td>Product Name: " + value.name + "</td><td>Price: " + value.price + "    </td><td>Description: " + value.description + "</td></tr>");
            });
        });
});
 $("#btnSearch").click(function() 
    {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Service/Rest/cart/get/cart",function(data)
        {
            var tb = $("#tab");
            $.each(data,function(i,value)
            {
                tb.append("<tr><td>Product Name: " + value.name + "</td><td>Price: " + value.price + "    </td><td>Description: " + value.description + "</td></tr>");
            });
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution for this, create a dummy table data with null value, and store your value in browser session and then replace all the null value on runtime through jquery/javascript.

Hope this helps.